# Configuration page for a custom timer job - how do I get the job definition?

Tags: development, timer-jobs, application-pages

Part of a project I'm working on involves creating a custom timer job which has some properties which are populated via the feature Template.XML file by default.

However, while this is sufficient for development purposes, it becomes a terrible hassle once it's used on a production server. So I wanted to create a configuration page for the timer job.

I've managed to create a custom Application Page visible in Central Administration. However, I'm struggling to get the actual `SPJobDefinition` object in the pages' code-behind.

Here's my current code:

```
        var jobs = new List<SPJobDefinition>();
        jobs.AddRange(SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.JobDefinitions);
        jobs.AddRange(SPFarm.Local.Services.SelectMany(s => s.JobDefinitions));
        return jobs.Where(j => j.Name == TimerJobs.SyncTimerJob.JobName).ToList();
```

The job definitely exists and is being executed, but the above code doesn't return the definition. (I know the above code isn't optimized - I've left it like that to see what results I get!)

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the definition for my custom timer job from an Application Page code-behind deployed in Central Administration?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution, so I'm posting it in case someone else has the same problem. It turns out I wasn't getting all the job-definitions in the system after all - I still had to check the job definitions for available web sites.

Here's the code:

```
        jobs.AddRange(SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications.SelectMany(wa => wa.JobDefinitions));
```

Now the code can be optimized (by adding `.Where` to the queries) and should return a custom timer job definition, ready for updating as needed.